# gradle on command line

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception, gradlew

I'm trying to execute my espresso tests via gradlew on command line. The build keeps failing and the following error is displayed.

I typed the following command

> gradlew test --stacktrace --info

Following error was displayed:

> Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.* Try:
>   Run with --debug option to get more log output.
>   * Exception is:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.
>           at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:72)
>           at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:82)
>           at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:32)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:253)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:182)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)quote

What is the possible solution?

Comment: I'm aware this question doesn't involve React Native, but the answers should still be valid in this instance, as it looks like you're using JDK 9.